# How to deal with good questions for which there are no existing answers?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

Hinduism is vast. But, there may be many good questions for which there may be no answers.

Suppose **what is the previous life of Krishna's wife Nagnajiti?** which may not be available, but the same is available for Satyabhama.

The same applies to **How many years does the king Rituparna ruled Ayodhya?**

How to deal with these questions, which are pretty on-topic but have no answers in Hinduism texts?

As per [statistics of area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/53689/hinduism) regarding our main site, more answering is needed and I suspect most of the questions that are unanswered falls into this category.

Comment: I am not sure but I think the possible work around is to write answer like "There is no detail available about Nagnajiti's previous life in text" with mentioning related chapters or sections where Nagnajiti is mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

Answer them. That is how to reduce unanswered stats.

If there are good questions, they deserve good answers too. So, write a good answer by yourself or let someone else by sharing who can answer better. When someone posts, vote on them. That is more important. Writing or upvoting some bad answers or any other half baked answer just to improve our stats is more harmful (applies to questions too). [There was one proposal about graduation](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1125/5212) if you remember. That was solely based on stats. We know what happened to it). We are not here to write for the stats. We are here for posting quality answers. It is quality which decides the improvement of the site and not Area 51 stats alone. Stats automatically improve when we write good content.

We can write answers from many sources and not only Hindu texts. We should only write *based on* them. In the name of quality, many are just quoting large passages from a book/scripture without much explaining anything of their own. If the answer percentage gets to 90 with the help of those answers, they are of no use. We need answers explaining in easy terms and helping the readers. Reduce answering in comments and to and fro discussion in comments. Using that time in writing a good answer can be fruitful. There are some comments which are expanded as answers. That's totally fine.

There can be hypothetical questions which may be related to Hinduism like "Is there a mention of advent of Europeans in India in Hindu texts?". Saying Hinduism is vast and letting this open is not a good way to deal with such questions. By saying Hinduism is vast, we will not have anything to close. That is where scope comes into the picture. So, we should allow practical questions which can be answered.

When we are getting good questions, let them come. Who knows, we may get a great answer just a day before the site is shut down. That is the beauty of the Stack Exchange model. There are many instances where there are great answers posted many years after the question is posted. We just have to be patient for good answers. We actually have a lot questions where the gap between question and answer is more than an year and bumped by the Community user a couple of times. A few questions off the top of my head are as follows:

[Who was Chhati Maiya?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9520/5212)

[Why does Thirumazhisai Alwar say the Pandava Thoothar statue of Krishna is older than him?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9980/5212)

[Who is the Kshetrapala god who lives on the Pariyatra mountains?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15994/5212)

Comment: Can you explain bit about how to answer such questions mentioned in question?

Comment: We just have to search. There will be answer somewhere. But there will be some hypothetical questions which we can't answer those questions.  [What to do with those type of questions whose answers are simple yes or no?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/612/5212). The questions mentioned are not a problem. But every character's previous lives are ont mentioned but there should be a reason why they think they will be mentioned.